# jQuery bind and 'click' evnts not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This jQuery (v1.9.1) snippet below works perfectly on all major browsers (including IE10), but does not work on IE9:

```
    <script>

    function alertPopup() {
      alert('hi');
    }

    $('#my-element').bind({
      click: alertPopup;
    });

    </script>
```

I learned that the `bind` method is supposed to be deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860018/jquery-function-bind-not-working-in-ie)), so I also tried changing the function to:

```
    $('#my-element').on('click', function() {
      alertPopup();
    });
```

And I also tried:

```
    $('#my-element').click(function() {
      alertPopup();
    });
```

And nothing seems to work. All three of the above functions work perfectly in IE10, Firefox, and Chrome. How can I get this to work in IE9?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What is the actual id of the element?

Comment: @epascarello, no errors in the console when I hit click the div...

Comment: clear the cache, make sure that it is running in IE9 mode and not IE7.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
$('#my-element').bind({
  click: alertPopup
});
```

or

```
$('#my-element').on({
    click: function() {
        alertPopup();
    }
});
```

or

```
$('#my-element').on('click', alertPopup);
```

or

```
$('#my-element').click(alertPopup);
```

Note that there are syntax errors in your code, like referencing a function with the parenthesis, adding a semicolon inside an object and closing it with `)}` and not `})`

Comment: Sorry for the syntax errors, I edited them above. I tried all of your suggestions and got the same result. Each one worked in my Mac's Firefox, but not on my PC's IE9. This might be a long shot, but is it possible that IE9 doesn't refresh the JavaScript each time the page is loaded, whereas Firefox does? If this is the case, I may have already tested the correct solution but didn't know it because the IE9's JS didn't reload.

Comment: @jball037 - could be, try hitting CTRL-F5